# Filtering using dplyr package

Tags: r, dplyr

My dataset is set up as follows:

```
User   Day
 10      2
 1       3
 15      1
 3       1
 1       2
 15      3
 1       1
```

I'n trying to find out the users that are present on all three days. I'm using the below code using dplyr package:

```
MAU%>%
  group_by(User)%>%
  filter(c(1,2,3) %in% Day)   

  # but get this error message: 
  # Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : Result must have length 12, not 3
```

any idea how to fix?

Comment: You may need `Day %in% 1:3` or `all(1:3 %in% Day)`

Comment: Thank you. But I believe that returns the OR, I'm looking for the AND. For example, User in Days 1,2, and 3. So my code output should return User 1.

Comment: You may need the second option i.e. `all(1:3 %in% Day)`

Comment: The second one worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Using the input shown reproducibly in the Note at the end, count the distinct Users and filter out those for which there are 3 days:

```
library(dplyr)

DF %>%
  distinct %>%
  count(User) %>%
  filter(n == 3) %>%
  select(User)
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 1
   User
  <int>
1     1
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "
User   Day
 10      2
 1       3
 15      1
 3       1
 1       2
 15      3
 1       1"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `all` to get a single TRUE/FALSE from the logical vector `1:3 %in% Day`

```
library(dplyr)
MAU %>% 
    group_by(User)%>%
    filter(all(1:3 %in% Day))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Groups:   User [1]
#   User   Day
#  <int> <int>
#1     1     3
#2     1     2
#3     1     1
```

#### data

```
MAU <- structure(list(User = c(10L, 1L, 15L, 3L, 1L, 15L, 1L), Day = c(2L, 
 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -7L))
```